# How can I output the Field Name in my template?

Tags: templating

I've created a plain text-field and added this field into a section.
I then created an entry and filled it with content.

I know I can output the content of the field in my template with `{{ entry.field_handle }}`, but is it also possible to display the field name? If so, how?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can get any field with [craft.fields](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.fields), which returns a FieldModel:

```
{% set field = craft.fields.getFieldbyHandle('field_handle') %}
{{ field.name }}
{{ field.instructions }}
```

.

**Note:** There is no documentation on the FieldModel yet, but if you want to know more, take a look at `craft/app/models/FieldModel.php`.

This is a list of all attributes supported by the Model:

- groupId
- name
- handle
- context
- instructions
- required
- translatable

Comment: I ended up finding this in the docs http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.fields With some tinkering I also found out that {{craft.fields.getFieldbyHandle('field_handle') }} will work.