# Output the contents of an instructions field within a Matrix block

Tags: matrix

As the title suggests, i'm trying to output the contents of a default instructions field within a Matrix block.  I'm sure it's doable but not sure where to start?

Thanks

Martin

Answer (score 2):

I just searched this Stack Exchange and found an answer on how to get the field model from the templates: [How can I output the Field Name in my template?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/493/125)

> You can get any field with craft.fields, which returns a FieldModel:
>
> ```
>  {% set field = craft.fields.getFieldbyHandle('field_handle') %}
>  {{ field.name }}
>  {{ field.instructions }}
> ```

Unfortunatelly, however, this won't work with fields within a Martix field. The `getFieldbyHandle` method is written for use in specific parts of the CP, where Craft knows the context the field is used in.

There's a `getFieldbyId` method though, which could work for your use case. The field's ID is independent from the context (inside Matrix or not).

Comment: Hi Carlcs, thanks for looking,  I should have said i'd already tried the method you also found.  I'll give the getFieldbyID a try.